# plotly.io.write_image doesn't save the image

Tags: python, image, io, plotly

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=count.index.tolist(),
                            values=count.values)])

fig.write_image(fig, 'fig1.png')
st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

I don't see any errors here but maybe I'm missing something. I've installed kaleido.
Exporting to HTML works fine

Comment: Same issue, any updates on that?

Comment: try : pip install -U kaleido, make sure your kaleido is newest. It works for me.